# dsPIC33CK Flash verify error when running project within MPLAB

Tags: pic, mplabx

I am trying to run simple routines on the dsPIC33CK Curiosity Nano board ([home page here](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/development-tool/EV88G73A)) with MPLAB X IDE v6.05. The code I generate builds successfully. I can also test it by directly dragging the hex file through the host PC file manager. However, when I try to run the code with MPLAB, the PKOB nano raises the following errors:

```
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - Flash verify error at 0x800000 (wrote 0x2C; read 0x00)
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - Flash verify error at 0x800000 (wrote 0x09; read 0x04)
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - Flash verify error at 0x800200 (wrote 0xA1; read 0x00)
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - Flash verify error at 0x800200 (wrote 0x02; read 0x00)
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - Flash verify error at 0x800202 (wrote 0x80; read 0x10)
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - 975 verification errors
common.debuggerbase - ERROR - PE verification failed!
```

This error is quite confusing to me, as I am trying the DEMO program that comes with the kit, and it is a board that I just bought.

Answer (score 0):

The dspic33 may become unresponsive to the integrated debugger if the configuration bits were incorrectly set by a previous program. I had the same problem and had to use my pickit4 to properly reconfigure the PIC. Ex.: the sample code contains "#pragma config ICS = PGD1" but this should be "#pragma config ICS = PGD3"

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am still able to re-program the dsPIC by the drag-and-drop feature, so I have re-programmed it with the correct ICS pin. The problem persists after this change